# iOS playing audio from URL

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, audio, audio-streaming

I need to make a simple iOS app that plays audio from this URL: 
http://listen3.rcast.pro:8000/keksfmvrn
when you tap the button.

How does one play music from a link like this?

Comment: **Show some research effort** - what have you done to try and solve this problem already?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want: [FreeStreamer](https://github.com/muhku/FreeStreamer/)